# How to print comma "," in the middle of sentenced when necessary, Part 1, Perl

Tags: perl

I need to print comma "," when the list more than one, and if more than one, the last list I don't want to print comma. I know I can use Join to to do this but I can't loop @NAMES with comma if there is another @FAMILIES to add in.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my @NAMES       = qw(ALLIES BOBBY CAKRA);
my @FAMILIES    = qw(A B C);


foreach my $names (@NAMES)
{
       foreach my $families (@FAMILIES)
       {
       print "$names, // $families\n";
       }
}
```

Expected Outcome:

```
ALLIES, // A
ALLIES, // B
ALLIES, // C
BOBBY, // A
BOBBY, // B
BOBBY, // C
CAKRA, // A
CAKRA, // B
CAKRA // C
```

Comment: @Shawn, yes. The code I shown you will permanently print the comma "," , I know I can use join ( "," ) but I can't figured it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see that there is an elegant and clean way since you need to drop the comma on the last element of both arrays.  Then add an explicit condition, while iterating over indices so to be able to single out the last elements

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

my @names       = qw(ALLIES BOBBY CAKRA);
my @families    = qw(A B C);

for my $n (0..$#names) {
    for my $f (0..$#families) {
        say $names[$n], 
            ( ($n == $#names and $f == $#families) ?  ' // ' : ', // '),
            $families[$f];
    }   
}
```

The parenthesis in the condition of the ternary operator `( ? : )` are needed for precedence. Another way is to use `&&` instead of `and`, which binds more tightly, but I didn't want the code to rely on 
a specific operator.

The syntax `$#ary` is for the index of the last element of `@ary`.

Comment: how about if I use hash? How can I iterate like what I use in array? - the question is updated

Comment: @Danial Haris, `@names = keys(%h); @families = values(%h);`

Comment: @ikegami, I can't use arrays or turn it into arrays from hash because I have sorted the data in a multidimensional hash. Do we have a way to do like array does? like $array[0], something like this because I have already tied the hash, so the order will be in place now?

Comment: @DanialHaris, uh, hashes can't be sorted. If it's not really a hash but one of those tied things, then what makes you think that `each` will preserve the order but not `keys`?

Comment: @ikegami, no. What I mean is I already sort the data into a multidimensional hash, and I tied it with the module to keep it in order. So, Can we do for hash like this e.g $hash{names}[0] to loop like arrays for this answer.

Comment: @ikegami, thank you! Actually thinking if hash works the same way as array to iterate it.

Comment: `$hash{ (keys(%hash))[0] }`, but calling `keys` like this repeatedly would be very inefficient compared to `$hash{ $names[0] }` as in zdim's code

Comment: @ikegami, I have updated the question so that I can learn something new and make it easier for us.

Comment: @DanialHaris  I was away for a while, just now could read these comments.  I'll look at it tonight

Comment: @DanialHaris  I don't regularly use tied things but here's what I see in  tests. The first-order keys in a tied hash (`AGILE`, `SMART`,.. in your case) are ordered and you could extract them with `keys` and have them in that order.  However, the _next_ order elements aren't and they'll just be "normal" hashy things -- inherently unordered (you can sort them on the fly).  I'd imagine that you can add tied hashes for every next order (dimension) but that'd be silly.  So the best I can say is, sort them (again) when printing. To get the original order use a hash to record it and use that in sort.

Comment: @DanialHaris  Also, I appreciate that you are responsive and working on your question, but this addition changes it greatly. There were 5 (five) answers before you added this and now none of them address it.  Since the addition is rather different perhaps you want another question on that?  Then I suggest think through it carefully so to ask the right thing. (And if you do end up with another question then remove this addition, so to leave the question as it was before the addition.)

Comment: @zdim, Okey okey. I will open up another question.

Answer (score 1):

Using `join` would generally be the best answer, but that would only work if you want to prevent a comma at the end of the line. (At least for a straight-forward answer, I'm sure you could hack it.)

You can make use of Perl's `$#array_name` variables inside a `for` loop to check when you're at the end of both lists, like so:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;


my @names       = qw(ALLIES BOBBY CAKRA);
my @families    = qw(A B C);

for my $i (0..$#names) {
    for my $j (0..$#families) {
    print "$names[$i]" . ($i == $#names && $j == $#families ? ' ' : ', ') . "// $families[$j]\n";
    }
}
```

Also, a just a note on style: the Perl Style Guide (try `perldoc perlstyle`) recommends using all-capital variable names only when they're constants. It's not a big deal, and definitely not required, but it can make it a little easier for others to follow your code. :)

Answer (score 1):

Special casing the last element is always messy, there are a bunch of trade offs, you just end up choosing which one looks less bad to you.

Another option compared to @zdim's perfectly good solution.

Note that I'm going to change @names and @families during execution, more tradeoffs, copying the array is the easy fix if it is a problem.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my @names       = qw(ALLIES BOBBY CAKRA);
my @families    = qw(A B C);

my $last_name = pop(@names);

foreach my $names (@names)
{
       foreach my $families (@families)
       {
           print "$names, // $families\n";
       }
}

my $last_family = pop(@families);

foreach my $families (@families)
{
       print "$last_name, // $families\n";
}

print "$last_name // $last_family\n";
```

Comment: Handles empty `@names` and/or empty `@families` "poorly".

Answer (score 1):

The alternative is to separate the output from the cross-product generation, and handling the last cast specially.

```
my @cross_product;
for my $n (0..$#names) {
    for my $f (0..$#families) {
       push @cross_product, [ $n, $f ];
    }   
}

if (@cross_product) {
   say "$_->[0], // $_->[1]" for @cross_product[0..@cross_product-2];
   say "$_->[0] // $_->[1]" for $cross_product[-1];
}
```

You can even avoid using up any memory as follows:

```
use Set::CrossProduct qw( );

my $i = Set::CrossProduct->new([ \@names, \@families ]);
my $N = $i->cardinality;
say sprintf '%1$s%3$s // %2$d', $i->get(), $_?',':'' for -$N+1..0;
```

Answer (score 1):

I thought of a variation to ikegami's (storing the results in a temporary array). There would be too many changes to comfortably fit in a comment, so here:

You could store the comma to the temporary list, too, and then remove it from only the last line.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my @names         = qw(ALLIES BOBBY CAKRA);
my @families      = qw(A B C);
my @output_lines;

foreach my $name (@names) {
    foreach my $family (@families) {
        push @output_lines, [$name, ',', ' // ' . $family . "\n"];
    }
}

if (@output_lines) {
    $output_lines[-1][1] = '';  # remove comma from last line
    print map { @$_ } @output_lines;
}
```